# Size of SeekBar thumb drawable changes when changing drawable programatically

Tags: android, size, drawable, seekbar

I am trying to create a SeekBar similar to the one in the Uber app for selecting a search type in my application. To do so, I believe the thumb drawable in the SeekBar should be changed programatically. As of now, the drawable is changed when it is supposed to, but the size of the drawable does not stay the same as defined in my resource file. The SeekBar is part of a Fragment.

Here is my layer-list resource file that I am using for the thumb drawable.
seekbar_thumb_size = 16dp.

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" android:innerRadius="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

            <size
                android:width="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size"
                android:height="@dimen/seekbar_thumb_size"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bars" android:gravity="center"/>

</layer-list>
```

It is supposed to display a circle with a border and a vector drawable icon centered in the circle. My preview gives me the following image:
[image]

Now, this is displayed properly in the SeekBar when the onStart method of my fragment is called. However, when I attempt to change the thumb drawable programmatically, it looks like the size of the circle is shrunk to match the height and width of the icon (shown below).

[image]

I have a feeling that this has to do with the way that I am retrieving the drawable during runtime. I have tried various approaches and continue to end up with the same result, a shrunken drawable.

Here are the approaches I have made to access the drawable:

I have declared a drawable object in the class:

```
    private Drawable BARS_DEFAULT;
```

1. Creating a Bitmap and using that for the drawable

   ```
   Bitmap bitmap1 =         
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.bg_bars_default);

   BARS_DEFAULT = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bitmap1);

   _seekbar.setThumb(BARS_DEFAULT);
   ```
2. (Deprecated) Getting the Resource drawable directly

   ```
   BARS_DEFAULT = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_bars_default);

   _seekbar.setThumb(BARS_DEFAULT);
   ```
3. Using ContextCompat

   ```
   BARS_DEFAULT = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.bg_bars_default);

   _seekbar.setThumb(BARS_DEFAULT);
   ```

All of these attempts lead to the icon being shrunk once the drawable is changed when the appropriate SeekBar value is reached.

One last thing, the change of the drawable is made in the onStopTrackingTouch method from the setOnSeekBarChangeListener interface.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a work around. For some reason the size of the icon wasn't staying the same because I was using a `dimen` value for the size of the icon in the layer-list. When I changed it to a hardcoded dp-value for the size of the circle, the icon was no longer shrinking during runtime.